# Using jquery to sort categories or tags based on an array

Tags: jquery, sorting

I consider myself an amateur web programmer and need some help.  What I am trying to do is sort either my list of categories or tags from blog posts on my site in a certain order for easier navigation.  The default sort order for the site can only be overridden with a script, and it is sorting by usage.  What I would like to do is sort it by a specific order, but not alphabetical - I'm thinking of sorting an array based on another array.  For example:

**Default Sort by Usage**

20, 15, 39

**Sorting Array** (which may contain items that are not on the website yet)

39, 30, 15, 31, 1, 60, 20

**Script Sort** (would sort what is found on the web page based on the order in which it is encountered in the sorting array)

39, 15, 20

Hope I am making sense - have no idea how to code for this.  I borrowed some code to sort alphabetically which is working, but as I mentioned earlier, I want to sort in a particular way.  This is what I have currently:

```
//Find out if a category list exists on the page
  if( $('.postsbycategory-block').length != 0 ){
    // Create empty array for later use
    var categories = []; 
    // Loop through each list item and get its name
    $('.postsbycategory-block ul li').each(function () {
      categories.push({
        categoryName: $(this).find('span.name').html(),
        listItem: $(this)
      });
    });
    // Sort the array by name
    categories.sort(function(a,b) {
      // Ensure a case-insensitive sort
      var c = a.categoryName.toUpperCase();
      var d = b.categoryName.toUpperCase();
      return (c > d) ? 1 : ((d > c) ? -1 : 0);
    });
    // Loop though each in order and move to end of HTML list.
    // That way, the first alphabetically ends up on top
    $.each(categories, function(index, object){
    object.listItem.appendTo(object.listItem.parent());
    });
 }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where would the numbers you wanna sort, come from?  IE how would you retrieve, 39,15,20.  Like what in the Post signifies a 39.  If you get what Im trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

It might go something like this...however, your categories array, would need a number/index in order for this to match against.  Otherwise its not really gonna work at all.

You weren't too clear on how/where those numbers are coming from.  So I just added an arbitrary theSearchKey variable, which fills with searchNum.

```
if( $('.postsbycategory-block').length != 0 ){


var categories = []; 
var sortingArray = [ 23,42,22,45,56];
var endResult = [];


$('.postsbycategory-block ul li').each(function () {
  categories.push({
    categoryName: $(this).find('span.name').html(),
    listItem: $(this),
    theSearchKey: searchNum //this will be where you put the #, that will match the sort keys
    // However you are retrieving that.  I dont know, so Im just putting searchNum here.
    // You could hide it in a data field on the li element and do
   // theSearchKey: $(this).data('searchKey');
  });
});

sortingArray.forEach(function(key) {
var found = false;
    items = categories.filter(function(item) {
        if(!found && item.theSearchKey == key) {
           endResult.push(item);
           found = true;
           return false;
        } else {
           return true;}
    })
})

$.each(endResult, function(index, object){
   object.listItem.appendTo(object.listItem.parent());
});
```

}

Comment: I use Squarespace to maintain my website, and the Categories list is actually books of the Bible.  The tags list is speaker name.  I'm not as concerned with the speaker name - that can be alpha.  For the books of the Bible, I would like for them to sort by how they appear in the Bible, not alpha.  Unfortunately, Squarespace will let you add the list of categories or tags, but it does not give sort options - it will sort only by frequency, then name.  For folks that visit my site, that sort option doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry I was vague with my example - was trying to simplify the problem, and thought talking about it in an array of numbers would be simpler.